# variant on weighted random number generaion

Tags: java, random

I need a weighted random number generator, to which you pass a function, the low and high values, and a peak value. So you can ask for uniform distribution (trivial); or for a triangle function using low, high, and peak; or a similar function but where the sides of the triangle are curved, or for a trig function, with its highest value coincident with peak, etc.

The literature includes several algorithms for weighted random number generation, but as far as I can tell, none which would allow these various functions to be manifested. I really don't want to use the brute-force method of creating an array with many entries for a high-probability choice, and few for low-probability ones, because I need to use this very frequently in a large program, and the low, high, and peak values will seldom be repeated.

Comment: What kind of input is the "function" you're referring to?  Is it a symbol for a kind of function such as "uniform", "triangular", etc.?  Or is it an arbitrary probability function (one that takes a number and returns a number)?  If the latter, this problem can be solved by rejection sampling: generate `x ~ U(low, high), y ~U(0, peak)` until `y < f(x)`.  Also what programming language are you using?

Comment: Aha! I will investigate rejection sampling - that's one I haven't known about. I haven't gotten to the point of creating some data structure for the functions. At the moment I expect I'll just call different methods depending on a String such as "cosine" or "triangle". I'm writing in java.